# Why the need to use « desquelles » here instead of « que »?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

> Je dois quand même avouer qu'il m'a fait vivre des choses à côté **desquelles** j'aurais pu passer.

I express this sentence in English as follows, and I suppose that « desquelles » serves the function of "that". But beyond that, I don’t know why the plain and simple « que » cannot be used here.

> "But I have to admit that thanks to him I’ve been able to experience some things close by **that** I might otherwise have missed out on."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence is "passer à côté **de** [quelque chose]", which, in English, is "to pass **by** [something]". It means, in this context, "to miss out on something". It is an integral part of the expression; in your translation you translated that part by "close by" which is not correct, it goes with "miss out on".

The "[quelque chose]" is, here, the relative pronoun "lesquelles". In English you would translate it by "which" or "that". It is contracted with "des" to produce "desquelles = des + lesquelles", exactly like "de + les = des".

Simply using "que" would have been incorrect here: "passer à côté" can only take an indirect complement. You cannot say "je suis passé à côté toi", you must say "je suis passé à côté *de* toi" (I passed by you).

So a correct translation of the second part becomes:

> But I have to admit that thanks to him I've been able to experience some things that I might otherwise have missed out on.

---

PS: Maybe the French sentence is easier to parse (but doesn't really sound good) if you split it in half:

> Je dois quand même avouer qu'il m'a fait vivre des choses. J'aurai pu passer à côté de ces choses.
>
> I have to admit that thanks to him I've been able to experience some things. I might have missed out on those things otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Is the use of "dont" incorrect as well? « Je dois quand même avouer qu'il m'a fait vivre des choses **dont** j'aurais pu passer à côté. »

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield *Dont* can be a plural. I can't think of any singular/plural distinction in the usage of *dont*. In this sentence, it wouldn't work in the singular either: “*il m'a fait vivre une chose dont j'aurais pu passer à côté” sounds just as wrong (it should be “… une chose à côté de laquelle j'aurais pu passer”). (I think that some French people might use *dont* in informal speech though.)

Comment: @LUNA You can't use *dont* here. I had to look up why: [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont) 1.I.B.a.α. If *dont* would be a complement of a noun that is itself has a preposition before it, then we use *duquel* (and feminine/plural variants) instead.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, you are correct. It is my mistake. *Example: Voici les clés dont elles ont besoin.*